# Having trouble deriving the symbols used in a quadratric approximation problem.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm refreshing my calculus by studying MIT OCW's Single Variable Calculus course online.

The problem is 2A-11, part of Unit 2 "Applications of Derivatives". It's a problem dealing with quadratic approximation. I'm understanding the concepts again fairly well and enjoying it, but sometimes things are glossed over in the solutions manual.

The problem is stated thus:

> 2A-11 For an ideal gas at constant temperature, the variables $p$ (pressure) and $v$ (volume) are related by the equation ${pv}^k = C$, where $k$ and $C$ are constants. If the volume is changed slightly from $\,v{}_0$ to  $\,v{}_0+\overrightarrow{D\,}v$, what quadratic approximation expressing p in terms of $\,\overrightarrow{D\,}v\,$ would you use? $\big(\text{Find the approximation valid for }\,\overrightarrow{D\,}v \approx0.\big)$

I started on it, but hit a wall, so I caved in and peeked at the answer...

> $${pv}^{\hspace{0.1ex}k} = c \quad\implies\quad p = {cv}^{-k}
> \\
> \begin{aligned}
> p &= {cv}^{-k}
> %\\ &
> =
> \big(v{}_0+\Delta v\big)^{-k}
> & \leftarrow &~~ \text{got this far}
> \\ &= {cv}{}_0^{-k}\left(1+\dfrac{\Delta v}{v{}_0}\right)^{-k}
> & \leftarrow &~~ \text{I assume this is their definition of function $f$,}
> \\ &&&~~\text{although I'm not clear  $f(?)$ of what argument.}
> \\&\approx
> \dfrac{c}{v{}_0^{\hspace{0.1ex}k}}
> \left(1 - k\hspace{0.1ex}\dfrac{\Delta v}{v{}_0} + \dfrac{k\left(k+1\right)}{2}\,\left(\frac{\Delta v}{v{}_0}\right)^{\!\!2}\right)
> \end{aligned}$$

**My question is**: How does the $\dfrac{\Delta v}{v{}_0}$ make its way into that approximation as the "$?$" in "$f(?)$"?

In other words, when they state things like *"when $x \approx 0$"*, they are relating that to "$f(x)$".
But somehow here, we have a $v{}_0$ in the denominator, and $\dfrac{\Delta v}{v{}_0}$ as a whole is taking the place of "$x$".

---

For reminder, the quadratic approximation is thus:

$$f(x) \approx f\left(x{}_0\right) + f'\left(x{}_0\right)\hspace{0.125ex}\left(x-x{}_0\right) + \dfrac{f''\left(x{}_0\right)}{2}\,{\left(x-x{}_0\right)}^2$$

So at $\,x_0 \approx 0$, it's:

$$f\left(x\right) \approx f\left(0\right) + f'\left(0\right)\,x + \dfrac{f''\left(0\right)}{2}\,x^2$$

Anyway, I see where it originated in the previous step in the answer by a refactoring of $v{}_0$, but I am hitting a wall trying to connect the two parts, and wasn't able to reach the answer myself.
Any light you can shed would be wonderful.

Comment: This is related to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series, just substitute $\alpha = -k$ and $x=\frac{\Delta v}{v_0}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$f(\Delta v):=p(v_0+\Delta v)=cv_0^k\left(1+{\Delta v\over v_0}\right)^{-k}$$
is an exact formula. Here $x:={\Delta v\over v_0}$ is a small quantity. For such cases we have the binomial series (which is nothing else but the Taylor series of $(1+x)^\alpha$ at $0$) given by
$$(1+x)^\alpha=1+\alpha x+{\alpha(\alpha-1)\over2}x^2+\>?x^3\ .$$
In the example at hand we have $x={\Delta v\over v_0}$ and $\alpha=-k$, so that
$$f(\Delta v)=1-{k\over v_0}\Delta v+{k(k+1)\over 2v_0^2}\Delta v^2+\>?\Delta v^3\ .$$